# Cannot connect to Azure Video Indexer API

Tags: azure, azure-video-indexer

I'm struggling for days trying to connect to an ARM Azure video indexer API. I followed up all the steps in this official [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-video-indexer/create-account-portal) ending up having an Azure Video Indexer resource. After that I generated a "Contributor"/"Account" token to upload a video (like explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-video-indexer/create-account-portal#management-api)) an get the following :

Request :

```
curl --request POST \
  --url 'https://api.videoindexer.ai/francecentral/Accounts/1ab75b03-5b0a-43be-885c-e19a96eb12f9/Videos?videoUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fdevweenaudioextract.blob.core.windows.**************2022-04-01_11-36-57_Segment.mp4&=&name=test&language=fr-FR&privacy=Private&priority=Low&indexingPreset=AudioOnly' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOi*************************nfc'
```

Reponse :

```
{
    "ErrorType": "AMS_AAD_APPLICATION_NOT_IN_TENANT",
    "Message": "Cannot connect to resource '/subscriptions/665eef5b-7230-43ad-9ec5-4afc5cd0a0e5/resourceGroups/ween-global/providers/Microsoft.Media/mediaservices/weenmediaservices' due to issue with AAD application 'f50b242c-c20f-4c50-8614-777fd3353784' that should have permissions to it. The AAD application wasn't found in the directory/tenant '72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47'. Trace id: '77f25c89-3796-43a9-9525-f7cda74d3b8d'."
}
```

I don't know what is this 'f50b242c-c20f-4c50-8614-777fd3353784' application their are talking about. I have tried a lot of things, but right now I'm stuck with this... If anyone has an idea it would help me a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Azure Video Indexer team is working on mitigating the issue, meanwhile what I can advise you is to use a User-assigned managed identify.

Seems the issue is related to the System assigned managed identity only.

Itai,

Product Manager @Azure Video Indexer

Comment: Ok thank you Itai, I will try this way ! :)

Comment: OMG it works ! More details on what to do if anyone else is having this issue :  I created a User-Managed-Identity that I assigned to my VideoIndexer resource and I registerd it as Contributor on my Mediaservice resource. After that I switched my videoIndexer to "user managed identity". After that I can access to the video indexer api !  : )

Comment: Hi @ItaiNorman, how can one dynamically generate the authorization bearer token needed to generate an operations token?